# Does imacro wait to run its command when its a "the connection is reset error" on my webpage?

Tags: imacros

Its common for my website to show this " connection is reset" error. I have to reload that page untill the page loads. Now i have to fill up forms everytime its a new page. I use reload plus addon to auto reload those crashed pages. so my question is will.my macro work in sync with reload plus and the connection in resets. So that my macro will wait for the page to load and till then auto reload will load the page and then my macro will proceed. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ‘iMacros’ always waits entire page loading to run its commands. Perhaps, you may use it instead of ‘reload plus addon’. If the question is still open, indicate the browser that you use.

Comment: I use mozilla firefox. Thank you. I got the answer i wanted.